# How to tell if a MP4 has video data and then convert it to an MP3 if there is only audio data in the file

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3

I have a mix of MP4 files some of them only have audio data while the others have video and audio data. I want to find a way to convert the ones that don't have any video data to MP3 without checking each file one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run on an input to check if it has video

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -map v -vframes 1 -c copy -f null -
```

The exit code will be 0, if it has video.